# What is wrong with this ICalendar

Tags: icalendar

I've tried this in a couple of validators.  It passes.  Can someone please advise what is wrong with this.  I doesn't load in any of our smart phones nor in Lotus Notes

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Company Name//NONSGML Intranet Outage Cal//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130421T000000
DTEND:20130421T003000
DTSTAMP:20130410T163211
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:nasl2webmaster@company.com
UID:calendar@company.com
LOCATION:EAF #1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Outage Calendar : added\, EAF #1 outage
PRIORITY:5
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
CLASS:PUBLIC
X-FRS-EXT-BUILDNO;X-FRS-SEND=SEND:8.03.80716
X-FRS-EXT-OPLINK;X-FRS-SEND=SEND:205A5936304D412A315F4B3026512E
X-FRS-EXT-RECTYPE;X-FRS-SEND=SEND:A
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT20H
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder:EAF #1 outage
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Any way you can add a little more detail to your question?  For example, maybe the process that you are trying?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating it from inside a stored procedure, it is being sent as an attachment to the email, extension is .ics.  It will not load on an iPhone running IOS6 nor on Lotus Notes.  Could it be that its being sent as an attachment using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a METHOD:REQUEST but your invitation has not ATTENDEE PROPERTY. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.2 which indicates which properties are mandatory.
If you just want to "publish" the event, you should use METHOD:PUBLISH (or no method at all).

There might be other issues of course but I would start by fixing this.

Finally, you are using floating time (no ending Z, nor timezone info in your DTSTART/DTEND). This is not invalid per say but, in general, calendar user agents don't like very much. You probably want to use zulu (utc) time instead. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5

Comment: I'me giving you credit because they were definitely issues that needed to be corrected.  The final answer was, I needed to move it to a clrProcedure and use the AlternateViews property

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? I can load it perfectly in Outlook, google calendar & iPhone.

Comment: In notes we get "Notes cannot process your file.  The content of this URL does not conform to the iCalendar parsing specifications."  And on the iPhone, we get no error message, it just doesn't work